# Nuxt Internal server error: Parse error, parse$e

Tags: nuxt.js

i tried looking everywhere but im not finding anything on this, the build completes and the application works but i do get this error from time to time

Note: i started having this error after upgrading from 3.7.3 to 3.10

```
ERROR Internal server error: Parse error @:271:26832
at parse$e (/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-9A4-l-43.js:16955:355)
at handleModuleSoftInvalidation (/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-9A4-l-43.js:49840:27)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async doTransform (/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-9A4-l-43.js:49635:10)
at async viteTransformMiddleware (/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-9A4-l-43.js:59342:32)
```

if anyone have any idea to point me in the right direction would really be appreciated.